# Scrapy shutdown crawler from pipline

Tags: scrapy

Is there a way to shutdown a scrapy crawl from the pipeline? My pipline processes urls and adds them to a list. When the list reaches a specified amount I want to shutdown the crawler. I know of `raise CloseSpider()` but it only seems to work when called from the spider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can call Crawler.engine.close_spider(spider_name, reason).

There is [an example in the CloseSpider extension](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/aa0e02dc54765342d970304cefa3207f8e67d736/scrapy/contrib/closespider.py#L63)